# Getting "asp.net ajax client-side framework failed to load" error message

Tags: ajax

I am using AJAX controls in my ASP.net application, and when i run the application locally, everything works fine.

Now, I deployed the app to one of testing servers and it looks like all the AJAX enabled controls are not working at all and I can see that there is an error while the page(where I use AJAX controls) is loading.

The error I am getting is "`asp.net ajax client-side framework failed to load`".

I googled it and it looks like I have to install the ASP.net AJAX extension on the server side.  But, how do you install the extension on the server?  Isn't it just a dll?  I already included the dll in the bin folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `System.Web.Extensions.dll` in the test server's GAC? Does its version match the one you're using on the dev machine?

Comment: hrm, I havent checked this yet.  But I will check that.  So, you need the "System.Web.Extension.dll" in order to use the Ajax? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It's part of the .NET Framework since 3.5, it was a separate download before.

Comment: So, if the server already has 3.5 framework installed, then i can assumed that the System.Web.Extensions.dll is intalled too.  But, i will double check this.

Comment: yes, unless you developed your app using System.Web.Extensions 1.6.x (.NET 2.0), in which case you'll need to jump through additional hoops.